I probably disallowed using the camera at some time in the past and now can't find a way to allow it again. How can I reenable it?
I am using my laptop for video conferences a lot, and somehow my webcam has stopped working in Firefox a couple of days ago. I believe I clicked "disallow" on the system's permission question, but I am not sure about that.
Can anybody help me get my webcam back in working order without me re-installing the whole system?
First thing I tried was rebooting, as is tradition.
Here is the environment:

Laptop including a standard UVC webcam.
Fedora Linux 41, Gnome 47, Pipewire 1.2.7-1.fc41 all updated to current versions.
Firefox from RPM, currently at 133.0.3.

Here is what works:

The webcam works just fine in other software (un-Googled Chromium, OBS, Gnome's "Camera" program).
Even in Firefox, I can still transmit the contents of my screen.
I can unzip a Firefox release from Mozilla's ftp, run the binary and use my webcam just fine.

Here is what used to work:

The webcam used to work in Firefox up until maybe five days ago, I was using it with BigBlueButton and other web-based tools all the time.

Here are things that I already checked in Firefox:

This does not work on any domain, it is not a simple "I denied that one website".
I double checked Firefox' camera permission settings including the domains and all the checkboxes in about:settings#privacy. The list of websites is now empty and it is is set to allow asking for permissions.
Trying to get any info about the video-related media devices in JavaScript in the browser's JavaScript console fails instantly. At the same time, getting audio devices leads to the standard "browser asks for permissions" and ultimately leads to the expected result for that type of media.




I tried setting about:config setting media.webrtc.camera.allow-pipewire to false, as suggested by a similar and recent discussion. That discussion is not fully applicable because they refer to a virtual v4l2-loopback camera, not an actual UVC device.
I created a new empty profile with firefox -no-remote -ProfileManager, on that profile, the behaviour is still the same.

Here are things that I already checked in the rest of the system:

Firefox is installed from rpm, not flatpak
Settings -> Privacy -> Cameras is set up in a way that generally allows access and also specifically allows firefox access to the camera. I have also off-and-on-again toggled this button for good measure.

I took a look at all pipewire clients, devices and sources with wpctl status and wpctl inspect $id for all involved ids. Those, that have the pipewire.access, display it as unrestricted.
I tried reading dbus-monitor --session, but I am pretty overwhelmed by the volume of logs and I don't really know what I would be looking for in there.
I tried reading pw-mon, but nothing in particular stood out.
I checked for dbus policies by looking at ~/.local/share/dbus-1/services/ but my user does not even have that particular directory.
I asked dbus for cameras with dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.freedesktop.portal.Camera" string:"IsCameraPresent" where it returned variant boolean true.
I asked dbus for the value of org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.Lookup and it came back as ({'': ['no'], 'org.gnome.Snapshot': ['yes'], 'org.mozilla.firefox': ['yes']}, <byte 0x00>).
I asked SELinux, if anything particular is up via sudo semanage boolean --list | grep mozilla, but all settings are on their defaults.


Using dbus in this case revealed the key piece of the puzzle.
Calling org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.Lookup with ('devices', 'camera') returned this line:

({'': ['no'], 'org.gnome.Snapshot': ['yes'], 'org.mozilla.firefox': ['yes']}, <byte 0x00>)

It is unclear, how the '': ['no'] got in there, but it probably still denied Firefox the desired camera access.
After calling org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore.DeletePermission with ('devices', 'camera', '') and then doing the Lookup above once more, the output was:

({'org.gnome.Snapshot': ['yes'], 'org.mozilla.firefox': ['yes']}, <byte 0x00>)

On my next attempt at accessing the camera, I got GNOME's Portal question ("do you want to let Firefox access your webcam?" or words to that effect) and accepting that gave me back camera support!

Huge thanks to @sheogorath who helped me with the dbus part and therefore provided the key piece of the puzzle and the eventual solution! Also thanks to Maximiliano from the gnome project for this post that helped immensely.
